# How to read a substring of a string separately with sscanf

Tags: c, scanf

I have line of assembly code that I am trying to parse into different instructions.
My test file here is

```
main:   add     $s0,$s1,$s2
        nor     $t0,$t1,$t2
        addi    $t0,$t1,50
```

arr[i].inst is populated with the instruction, the tab, then it's addresses on each line. So basically, each arr[i].inst starts with add nor and addi 
The statement

```
if ((sscanf(arr[i].inst, "%[add]add", temp) == 1)
    printf("add");
```

Will successfully print "add" every time an add instruction shows up. But how can I make it so it does not read add from addi? These are two instructions, and I need addi excluded so a different if statement below this one will test for addi and print it

Comment: Your code will print `add` if the input contains `a`, `da`, `dad`, and other sequences of `a` and `d`. The trailing `add` in the format string will never match, but there's no way for that call to `sscanf()` to tell you that.  You're trying to do it wrong.  You should consider scanning for `"%[a-z]"` and then comparing the string with various choices.  Making `sscanf()` scan for each instruction type is not a good way to work, but that seems to be what you are trying.

Comment: you just picked the best language to parse strings: C (and I just been painfully reminded of character ranges in scanf :))

Comment: Something like `scanf("add%*[ \t]")` might do the trick, but this is really a job for regex's I think.

Comment: I got it. I decided to just put test for addi, which includes add. then add other if statements inside that tests of temp is add or addi and prints it

Comment: @xing relying on tabulations as separators is dangerous for assembly language. Assemblers accept spaces as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I noted in a comment:

> Your code will print `add` if the input contains `a`, `da`, `dad`, and other sequences of `a` and `d`. The trailing `add` in the format string will never match, but there's no way for that call to `sscanf()` to tell you that. You're trying to do it wrong. You should consider scanning for `"%[a-z]"` and then comparing the string with various choices. Making `sscanf()` scan for each instruction type is not a good way to work, but that seems to be what you are trying.

Assuming op-codes must be in all lower-case and none of them are longer than 19 characters and the characters in an op-code are all basic Latin alphabet, then maybe this is what you're after:

```
char opcode[20];

if ((sscanf(arr[i].inst, " %19[a-z]", opcode) == 1)
{
    if (strcmp(opcode, "add") == 0)
        printf("%s\n", opcode);
    else if (strcmp(opcode, "addi") == 0)
        printf("%s\n", opcode);
    else if …
}
else
{
    …handle error…
}
```

The leading space in the format skips over leading spaces; `%[…]` scan sets, `%c` and `%n` are the only conversion specifiers that do not automatically skip leading space.

You might decide you should worry about over-long names presented as opcodes; there are ways to deal with them with `sscanf()`, but I'd probably not be using it for this job.  I'd use some tokenizing code. I wouldn't use `strtok()`, though there's an outside chance `strtok_r()` or `strtok_s()` could be used; I'd be more likely to use `strspn()` instead.

The code finding the opcode match needs serious work too.  It should be driven from a table of valid opcode names, probably in sorted order so a binary search can be used to find the match.  There would be auxilliary information associated with that table to tell the recognition code what is valid after the opcode.